# JSON Patch diffing fails due to ObjectMapper?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, json-patch

I have 2 objects that I'm trying to diff. For this purpose I use `Jackson ObjectMapper` in spring-boot version 2.1.3 to de-serialize them to a String, read them as a tree (convert to `JsonNode`) and then diff them to create a `JsonPatch` object. What I do notice is that in the existing object's JsonNode all the fields having `null` values are skipped as are objects having only `null` valued fields. The `ObjectMapper` seems to be behaving differently in the consumer (spring-boot version  2.6.7) and service provider (spring-boot-2.1.3). Sample, within the tree:

```
"_optionalAttrs":{"styles":{"99_0002_4_24_002":{"hineck":null,"choices":{"99_0002_4_24_002_001":{"color":null}}},"99_0002_4_24_001":{"hineck":null,"choices":null}}.
```

vs

```
"_optionalAttrs":{"styles":{"99_0002_4_24_002":{"choices":{"99_0002_4_24_002_001":{}}},"99_0002_4_24_001":{}}
```

I am guessing this is the reason why the JsonPatch operations generated are incorrect :

```
op: copy; from: "/_optionalAttrs/styles/99_0002_4_24_001/hineck"; path: "/_optionalAttrs/clientAttributes/channel"
```

and I end up getting this error - no such path in target JSON document. Is there a way to ensure that the two remain consistent? If you think there are any other issues please let me know. The consumer code is something we can change but the service provider code is not in our ownership. I am using `json-patch-1.12` and `jdk 11`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `ObjectMapper` will keep `null` values, but you can skip them using the following setting:

```
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
```

Comment: Yeah, I just found out that our service provider uses this `objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);` and we don't in our consumer code. Changing it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I have not good solution, but it's better then nothing
You can map object to Map<String, String> with *fieldAndValueMap* method and compare them

```html
    public Map<String, String> fieldAndValueMap(Class<?> type, Object obj) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
        for (Field field : type.getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if (isWrapperType(field.getType())) {
                String value = nonNull(field.get(obj)) ? field.get(obj).toString() : "null";
                result.put(type.getSimpleName() + "." + field.getName(), value);
            } else {
                String getMethod = "get" + Character.toUpperCase(field.getName().charAt(0)) + field.getName().substring(1);
                Method method = type.getMethod(getMethod);
                Object subObj = method.invoke(obj);
                if (nonNull(subObj)) {
                    result.putAll(fieldAndValueMap(field.getType(), subObj));
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public boolean isWrapperType(Class<?> type) {
        return getWrapperTypes().contains(type);
    }

    private Set<Class<?>> getWrapperTypes() {
        Set<Class<?>> ret = new HashSet<>();
        ret.add(Boolean.class);
        ret.add(Character.class);
        ret.add(String.class);
        ret.add(Byte.class);
        ret.add(Short.class);
        ret.add(Integer.class);
        ret.add(Long.class);
        ret.add(Float.class);
        ret.add(Double.class);
        ret.add(Void.class);
        ret.add(BigDecimal.class);
        ret.add(LocalDate.class);
        ret.add(LocalDateTime.class);
        ret.add(LocalTime.class);
        ret.add(Date.class);
        return ret;
    }
```

*to get object as map of fields and values*: fieldAndValueMap(firstObject.getClass(), firstObject)